Error during Gromacs2024.2 installation: srot & strsm
I was trying to install GROMACS following the installation guide from the GROMACS webpage (https://manual.gromacs.org/documentation/2024.2/install-guide/index.html) but after running:
sudo make install
the installation gives back two errors:
[100%] Built target nblib
[100%] Linking CXX executable ../../../bin/argon-forces-integration
/usr/bin/ld: /opt/gromacs-2024.2/build/lib/libgromacs.so.9: undefined reference to srot_' /usr/bin/ld: /opt/gromacs-2024.2/build/lib/libgromacs.so.9: undefined reference to strsm_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [api/nblib/samples/CMakeFiles/argon-forces-integration.dir/build.make:100: bin/argon-forces-integration] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:3767: api/nblib/samples/CMakeFiles/argon-forces-integration.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:166: all] Error 2
*I saw someone saying that installing the LAPACK-devel package helped with the same error but I tried that and it didn´t work.
I would appreciate any help with the issue. Thank you!

Can you ensure if LAPACK and BLAS are installed ,
sudo apt-get install libblas-dev liblapack-dev.
Also install latest GCC and G++:
sudo apt-get install gcc  g++
Also you can alternatively try to install it using conda , which will bypass errors caused from source code installation,
https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/gromacs

Both packages were installed already,  but I tried installing through conda and it worked like that! Thank you so much :)
